# Create C Source MEX File from several cpp files

Tags: c++, c, matlab, mex

I have a program in C++ including several cpp and .h files.
I would like to create a mex file to call C++ function in MATLAB. In this [link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/standalone-example.html),  they have talked about creating C source MEX file from only one C function. How can I do that for a program in C that has several sub-functions saved in several files, as well as several libraries?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In 2008 you could provide the libraries and link them on the compiler command line just like with a regular C or C++ program. I doubt this has changed much.

Comment: @user4581301 this is exactly right. The `mex` command can take any number of source files and library files or -l linker commands.